# ASP NET 4 ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider Login command

Tags: asp.net, debugging, asp.net-membership

I'm using the default Login.aspx in an ASPNET 4 WebForms application.

I have configured the `System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider` and I tested using the `Membership.ValidateUser` function and everything works fine. I'm able to validate a test user.

Although, when I insert the same test username and password in the Login.aspx I always receive a login error. I can't figure out what's going on.

The next step is to try debugging what's going on behind scenes. I have downloaded the net framework symbols, but I don't know how to set a breakpoint in the "Login" handler of the `LoginButton` in Login.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer myself. I was handling the Authenticate event with no code inside. This was preventing the Login control to Login against the ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider.